# Script not working when run automatically

Tags: linux, script, bash-scripting, gnupg, autostart

This script (parts of it) **runs perfectly** when invoked manually from the Terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ "`ps -e | grep -c $(basename $0)`" -gt "2" ]] && echo -e "`basename $0`: Mutiple instances found. Terminating this process." && exit 1

cd "`dirname $0`"
notify-send -u low "Script started"

[ .. some variables ..]

auth=`gpg -q --no-use-agent --passphrase-file $HOME/passphrase -d ./encrypted_auth`
wget --post-data """$auth""" --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies a -qO /dev/null "$post"

[ .. some more script ..]
```

The problem, is that **it doesn't run** when placed in the Startup Applications (GNOME Shell).

Can you please help me fix this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you determining that it doesn't run?

Comment: Please do not crosspost without telling so, and don't do it anyway if you didn't receive attention for some time. This just leads to duplicate effort in answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In order not to have problems with the first line, make sure to kill all your script instances when (re)testing. e.g. `killall <scriptname>`.

2) Add the `--batch` parameter to your `gpg` command.

Everything else should fine. Hope this helps.